# Django username only unique for active user

Tags: python, django, function, django-models, field

I've created a custom model User with the field username (char field) and active (boolean field). The username field should only be unique when the user is active, otherwise, I want to rename the user to 'inactive' so the username can be reused by a different user. How can this be done? I tried this, but it throws an error:

```
class User(models.Model):
  username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=isActive())
  active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

  def isActive(self):
    return self.active
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with a [**`UniqueConstraint`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint) with a `condition=…`:

```
from django.db.models import Q


class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=('username',), condition=Q(active=True)
            )
        ]
```